# Rails: How can I render a block with ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have a model "Thing" which has_many "Comments". I want the list of @thing.comments to refresh with ajax when the "post a comment" button is pressed.

This code works to list the text of the first comment:

**view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#post").click(function () {
    $.get( "<%= postcomment_thing_path(:id => @thing.id) %>", function( data ) {
      $('#comments_h2').html(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**controller:**

```
def postcomment
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  render text: @thing.comments.first.text.to_s
end
```

But when I try to print the whole comment block, it only prints one single "#".

**controller:**

```
def postcomment
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  render text:
    @thing.comments.each do |comment|
      comment.text.to_s
    end
end
```

How can I print the text for all the comments?

Comment: Try replacing the each with map and use joins to combine the results.
`@thing.comments.map { |comment|
      comment.text.to_s
}.joins("<br>")`

Comment: It's returning "undefined local variable or method "comment" ", are you sure that's the right syntax?

Comment: Yes. But I do have a mistake @thing.comments.map { |comment| comment.text.to_s }.join("<br>"). Should be join, not joins.
Another thing, I would use render_to_string instead of render :text, but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Do you know why it might be returning that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load all comments when a new one is posted, you load the old ones with rails and display them, then with ajax you append/prepend a new one to the list of old ones.

- http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/

I assume your comments are in a div:

```
<div class="comments">
  <% @thing.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment_<%= comment.id %>">
      <%= comment.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

you form where you add a comment should have `remote: true`:

```
<%= form_for @comment, remote: true do |f| %>
   inputs here
<% end %>
```

when you add a comment, I assume it's action create that's being called, so you'll need a `create.js.erb` file in `app/views/comments/` folder and a `_comment.html.erb` in the same location.

`create.js.erb` will contain your js code that will append/prepend the comment to the `div.comments` element:

```
<% if @comment.valid? %>  // @comment should be loaded in controller create action.
  $('div.comments').append("<%= j(render(@comment)) %>");
  $("#new_comment")[0].reset();
<% else %>
  alert("Can't add comment");
<% end %>
```

Comment: What would _comment.html.erb contain?

Comment: comment content, for example `<%= @comment.content %>`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "remote: true" to your "post comment" button. From there, you can have your controller respond_to |format| and have the data updated in realtime.

More information about working with ajax in Rails found [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Well, while its not a good idea to be displaying all the comments again as suggested by @rmagnum2002. You should be appending or prepending the current comment based on your requirements. However, to get the current code working you must make some changes

```
def postcomment
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  comment_text = ""
  @thing.comments.each do |comment|
     comment_text += comment.text.to_s
   end 
  # you could use map and join them by a delimiter also 
  render text: comment_text        
end
```

and that should render what you expect.

Hope that helps